# C++ error 0xC0000005 caused by pointers/dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to implement MergeSort using pointers , and everything works until i call the function multiple times in a row , then the code breaks and returns this error 0xC0000005 . I'm assuming it's due to memory getting full since i'm not deallocating it. I'm new to dynamic memory and pointers and don't really know how to fix it.

```
int* MergeV1(int *x,int n,int *y,int m)
{
    int i=1,j=1,l=0;
    int *aux=new int[n+m+1];
    while(i<=n&&j<=m)
    {
        while(i<=n&&x[i]<=y[j])
            aux[++l]=x[i++];
        while(j<=m&&y[j]<=x[i])
            aux[++l]=y[j++];
    }
    while(i<=n)
        aux[++l]=x[i++];
    while(j<=m)
        aux[++l]=y[j++];
    return aux;

}
int* MergeSortV1(int* v,int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return v;
    int m=n/2;
    int lenst=m;
    int lendr=m;
    if(n%2)
        lendr++;
    int *s,*d;
    s=MergeSortV1(v,lenst);
    d=MergeSortV1(&v[m],lendr);
    return MergeV1(s,lenst,d,lendr);
}
```

Comment: You should run it in a debugger and see where it breaks.

Comment: Note that, in C++, array indexes begin at **zero** and end at `n-1`. So you probably want to change `int i=1,j=1,l=0;` to `int i=0,j=0,l=0;` and `while(i<=n&&j<=m)` to `while(i < n && j < m)` (and similarly in the other `while` loops`).

Comment: You'd need a lot of leaks to exhaust your whole memory. Are you sure you are accessing your arrays correctly? Indexes in C++ start from 0, not from 1.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I know it's not a good practice but i usually use array from 1 to n , and declare them with n+1 size. I'm gonna try to use the debugger. Thought it might have been a simple solution i din't know about that's why i asked here, thank you !